# Elixir: Pattern match a list of specific type?

Tags: elixir

I have a list of structs of an arbitrary size.

Let's call it `l`.

`l = [%X{a:1}, %X{a:3}, %X{a:9}, %X{a:11}]`

The size of `l` keeps changing. What I'd like to know is how do I pattern match against `l` to ensure it always is made up of structs of `%X{}`. I want the pattern matching to fail if the list contains something else. For example:

`l = [%X{a:1}, %X{a:3}, %Y{a:9}, %Z{a:11}]`

**Things I've tried**

```
i = %X{}
j = %Y{}

[%X{}|_] = [i,i,i]
```

But that matches only the first element.

```
[%X{}|_] = [i,j,j]
```

Should fail for my use case, but it doesn't.
Maybe if there's an operator or something like this, that will match a list of specific type, that's exactly what I'm looking for:

```
[%X{}+] = [i,i,i] # Doesn't exist, just an example
```

**Some background**

I'm on phoenix and I have a model `post` with `has_many` relationship with `images`. A given user could upload multiple images and I'd like to pattern match to make sure I'm working with the right struct (`%Plug.Upload{}`) in this case.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot pattern match on every element of a list (without recursion). In this case I'd use `Enum.all?/2` and the `match?/2` macro:

```
if Enum.all?(list, &match?(%X{}, &1)) do
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

While the answer by @Dogbert is perfectly valid, I personally find the explicit clauses to be more succinct:

```
all_are_x =
  Enum.all?(list, fn
    %X{} -> true
    _ -> false
  end)
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, what you are looking for doesn't exist: you cannot pattern match on every element of a list.

You can use [Enum.map/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2), to crash at the first non `%X{}` element:

```
Enum.map(l, &(%X{}=&1))
```

---

To pattern match, I used:  `%X{} = something`, while Dogbert used:  `match?(%X{}, &1)`

The difference is that first one fails if it doesn't match, while the second one returns `false`. If you want to stick to "*let it crash*" of elixir, you might be interested in the first one, while in most of the case you will prefer to use the second one, like this for example:

```
k == Enum.reject(l, &match?(%X{}=&1))
k == [] || IO.inspect(k)
```

[Enum.reject?/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reject/2) used with [match?/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#match?/2) will not crash and return a list of all the element that are not an X structure.

Comment: @Dogbert's answer is better, since it will return false if the list contains a struct that is not of type `X`. it also enumerates the whole list only if all elements are of struct `X`, hence making it faster.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is the one that answers the question to the point "I want the pattern matching to fail is the list contains something else. ".
However, for the benefit of others searching an answer to this question and for the performance consideration, I'll accept the other one. But, thanks a lot Nathan.

Comment: @dsignr I fully understand, and I acknowledge that in most of the case people are going to look for Dogbert's solution

Comment: Also, if you want to crash on a match failure, you don't really need to check if the returned value is `[]` because if that's the case, an exception would have already been thrown.

Comment: that is accurate, initially, I was not expecting the pattern matching to crash. Now, I would either use `Enum.map` with pattern matching that crashes, or `Enum.reject` with `match?`, in order to know what element were not pattern matched. I edited the answer in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

**How I ended up solving this:**

As described in my question, I was trying to match each instance of uploaded file to ensure it's a `%Plug.Upload{}` struct. I should have mentioned I am on Phoenix. The good thing on Phoenix is you can add this sort of validation directly into your models - that's what changesets and their validations are for! And they will be validated automatically for each instance of the model being saved to the database.

So, I ended up adding a custom validation in my `image.ex` model.

So, my changeset ended up looking like:

```
  @doc false
  def changeset(image, attrs) do
    image
    |> cast(attrs, [:title, :description, :alt, :src, :sequence, :file])
    |> ensure_valid_upload()
    |> validate_required([:file])
  end
```

Having said that, I did also end up using the accepted answer in other areas of my code which weren't directly related to my models.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I do this way when I want only atoms for example. I is rather blatant but I like keep the code explicit at usage:

```
  def only_atoms(list) when is_list list do
    Enum.map(list, &only_atom/1)
  end

  def only_atom(x) when is_atom x do
    x
  end
```

I guess it is rather like the crash version of *@Aleksei Matiushkin*. Would be nice to have something more general available as a guard clause.